# How to specify the size of a database parameters with schema on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I tried to initialize a database with a `schema.sql` file for PostreSQL in Heroku but I have a problem with the size I want to date the parameters of the table. In effect with the line `id int (11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY` I get the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
```

Here is the file `schema.sql`

```
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(100),
  email varchar(100),
  username varchar(30),
  password varchar(100),
  register_date timestamp not null
);
```

And here is the error:

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/myflaskapp$ heroku pg:psql < schema.sql--> Connecting to postgresql-clean-86569
NOTICE:  table "users" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   id int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
                ^
NOTICE:  table "articles" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:   id int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
                ^
```

Comment: `int` does not take parameters. If you want to limit the values you can store in that column use a check constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong (and I'm pretty sure), postgresSQL doesn't accept `int` sizes but `NUMERIC`.
You can do `columnName NUMERIC(11)` 
Or with a constraint, forcing to being between ranges

Comment: That's a bad advice. `numeric` takes up much more space than `int` and is slower as well. Additionally: in MySQL `int(11)` does **not** limit the values of the column in any way.

Comment: Then, a constraint will be the best way.